# mail() not working on my virtual machine

Tags: php

Mail() is not working on my virtual machine.

I would like to use it for my php application. What can I do?

What settings should I configure in php.ini to have it work>

I am using sendmail and when I look at the mail logs it tells me "Connection timeout" what can I do?

Also when I do from terminal on my centos server:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
```

it blocks and doesn't output anything.

Comment: Can you please clarify "not working" ? Are there errors, are you not receiving the email, is it not sending?

Comment: what error did you get...

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a mail server on your machine for the mail function to work. If you are on Windows (which I am guessing) you can setup a [Pegasus mail server](http://www.pmail.com/). Connecting to either your ISPs SMTP server or GMail or whatever is the easiest route out of this one.

You need to define SMTP settings in your php.ini to talk to a mail server through which you are allowed to send outbound messages, with or without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working from wamp or xamp then u have to pear mail or some other library to support your configuration. I used pear http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/  ...... it will also contain test mail sending tutorial